# Change Text Field Once Drop Down Has Been Selected (Multiple forms on 1 page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm looking to change the value of a `<p>` tag once an option from a drop down has been selected. I have that working but my issue is I am going to have lots of forms on one page and feel like I am repeating my code. Is there a way to do this with a function for example? To save me writing a new section of javascript everytime a form gets added to my page?

My javascript code:

```
    $('.orderProduct select#packageOption').change(function(){
        $('#packagePrice').html($(this).val());
    });

    $('.orderProduct2 select#packageOption').change(function(){
        $('#packagePrice2').html($(this).val());
    });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `data-element-id` attribute to each `select` like:

```
<select data-element-id="packagePrice">...</select>
<select data-element-id="packagePrice2">...</select>
```

then you simply need this jQuery code:

```
$('select[data-element-id]').change(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var id = $this.data('element-id');    
    $('#' + id).html($this.val());
});
```

If you want to avoid the extra attribute you could use jQuery's DOM traversing functions, to locate which `p` you should update.